# Nodejs Post Request no data in console

Tags: node.js, angular, form-data, body-parser

Not able to get any data in the following post request , any suggestions ?

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var urlEncodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false});
var app = express();
// add Service
app.post('/api/service/addService',urlEncodedParser, (request, result) => {
if (!request.body) return result.sendStatus(400);
     console.log(request.body);
     console.log(request.params);
});
```

Comment: Check in console that whether request is getting hit or not. Debug the code. May be you will get something

Comment: Can you show an example request?

Comment: How do you make your request via your front? You can use postman too

Comment: i am using postman

Answer (score 0):

Will you try this

```
var app = express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

after that write your code -

```
app.post('/api/service/addService', (request, result) => {
if (!request.body) return result.sendStatus(400);
     console.log(request.body);
     console.log(request.params);
});
```